# How to purge queued messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

[image: e]

I have a situation where messages are not getting cleared from Que (please refer to above pic), and I am not sure which que they belong to, so how do I figure that out and how to purge these queued messages.

any additional messages coming in are being cleared but these 21 messages are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it,Under Ques sort by Total or ready then click on that Que and Perge messages.